# Nesting vectors as function returns Clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

When I put the below function into `leon repl`, I get
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)`

Another answer suggested putting the first call to `vector` inside of an anonymous function with `#`, but that then throws two `java.lang.Exception: Unmatched delimiter: )` I'd like to return a nested vector, of the form `[ [maxLat, maxLong ] [minLat, minLong ] ]` How can this be done?

```
(defn bounding-box [lat lng dist] (
    (vector
    (vector (+ lat (to-degs (/ dist (p-radius dist)))) (+ lng (long-dist lat dist))) ;maxLat, maxLong
    (vector (- lat (to-degs (/ dist (p-radius dist)))) (- lng (long-dist lat dist))) ;minLat, minLong
  )
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format your code more carefully!

You just need delete bracket after function args `[lat lng dist] (` and the last one `)`

Comment: Yeah I'm having trouble with how to format clojure (coming from a Ruby background.) Any tips?

Comment: You can get the paredit mode in Eclipse as well, but not sure how good it is. But paredit wins hands down for matching s-expressions.

Comment: Paredit is best, but wouldn't really help with this issue. Really all you need to do is not put parens on their own line, or have a `(` that's not immediately followed by whatever you're calling; that is, never put a newline before a close paren, or after an open paren. Then this mistake is easy to spot.